# Generating valid .zip files in Azure DevOps - Compressed folder is invalid

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps build pipeline. In that pipeline, I have the following tasks:

**dotnet build**

```
Path to project(s): ./MyConsoleApp/MyConsoleApp.csproj
Arguments: --configuration Release --output ../content
```

**Archive Files**

```
Root folder or file to archive: ./content
Prepend root folder name to archive paths: unchecked
Archive type: zip
Archive file to create: content.zip
Replace existing archive: checked
```

**AzureBlob File Copy**

```
Source: content.zip
Destination Type: Azure Blob
RM Storage Account: "<mystorageaccount>"
Container Name: "content"
Blob Prefix: MyConsoleApp/content
```

This build pipeline runs successfully. I can see the .zip file successfully created and in my Azure Storage account. The size looks like an appropriate size for the console app. However, I'm unable to unzip the .zip file.

When I download the .zip file from Azure Storage, I then try to "unzip" it. I do this by right-clicking on the .zip file in File Explorer nd choosing "Extract All...". I click "Extract" and I get an error that says:

```
The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\content.zip' is invalid.
```

I don't understand this. Everything looks correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you compressing the file on a Windows agent or a Linux agent?

Comment: @DanielMann How can I tell? I just created a new build pipeline using Azure DevOps (the cloud version, not on premise). I see "run on agent" for the job. However, I don't see where to specify, or check, which OS is being used.

Comment: What agent queue does it say you're using?

Comment: The "Agent pool" is listed as "<inherit from pipeline>". I don't see the "agent queue" listed anywhere.

Comment: Look at the "Pipeline" section of the build definition.

Comment: In the "Pipeline" section of the build definition, I see a field named "Agent pool". That value is set to "Hosted VS2017"

Comment: Okay, that's a Windows agent. Have you tried publishing your zip file as a build artifact and downloading it from there, in order to identify whether the zip file itself is corrupted, or whether something is happening as part of the blob copy process to your storage account?

Comment: @DanielMann How do you "publish the zip file as a build artifact and download it from there"? I assume you mean to select "Zip Published Projects" in the `dotnet build` task. But I don't know how to download it. Where does it get stored? If I'm wrong, please let me know. Oh, and also, thank you SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts

Comment: @DanielMann Where does one actually download the .zip file from? Is there a URL or something I can visit to see the .zip file and grab it? I can't seem to find anything in the docs related to this. Thank you!

Comment: You can download it from the build artifact after build is finished.